# Convert Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, github, terminal, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I previously was working with git and github on the command-line. I downloaded sourcetree and played around with bitbucket, just to see what is the best option. I think I accidentally migrated Bitbucket on the command-line somehow. Because now when I do git init and try to push, nothing is happening on github. Then I tried to delete all the access keys from my mac and tried to reinstall github with the ssh keys but thats doesnt seem to work. when I did git pull - i got the following [image: terminal line]
How do I delete bitbucket and go back to work on github on my command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "I accidentally migrated Bitbucket on the command-line"? Bitbucket is a hosting service for your repositories. It has no bearing on what happens at your command line. Also, you write: *when I do git init and try to push, nothing is happening on github*. You shouldn't expect anything to get pushed right after initialising a fresh repository. You first have to set up a *remote* (i.e. a link to an existing repository hosted on GitHub) for that.

Comment: I am really new at this. Thank you for your suggestions.  I thought git init would make an empty repo on github and i would be able to automatically add commit and push to master. I didnt understand at first.

Answer (score 2):

On GitHub you will find your repository URL down the right hand side

[image: github]

Copy this URL as you will need it. Now start up terminal and navigate to the directory where your git repository is. Run the following and you should see your bitbucket set as origin,

```
git remote -v
```

we need to remove it and replace it with your github one. We can do it like this

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:ollieatkinson/OKAMutableDirectedGraph.git
```

Now you should be able to push/pull as you normally would do! Remember to replace the remote URL with your own.

Comment: Markdown formatting tip: don't use the three-backtick syntax on Stack Overflow. Instead, indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: Will I have to keep doing this over and over again to each repo?

Comment: @user3730179 you should only have to do this once per repository - you can have multiple remotes too, so if you wanted to still be able to push to bitbucket and github at the same time.

Comment: git remote -v doesn't return anything

Comment: I dont want bitbucket - I just want github now :(

Comment: You should see something like (http://i.imgur.com/yho2L1y.png) if you have any remotes - if not just add a new origin!